# VBA Variant MsgBox Format To Per Cent (%)

Tags: vba, formatting, msgbox

```
Sub PctTest()
   Dim Third As Variant
   Third = 1 / 3    
   MsgBox (Third)
End Sub
```

How do I get the msgbox to display the variable "Third" as 33.33%?  I know how to format a cell but I have looked around and don't understand how to format a variable like this.  Thanks in advance- Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in: `FormatPercent(1 / 3, 2)`

Comment: Thanks @peter!  that was easy, but I somehow missed it in the "F2" lookups.  That is great! Have a great weekend! Tommy

Comment: Follow up for others- if you use "Third = FormatPercent..." or Third = Format..." you can't then operate with that number.  In other words if the next line you try to do something like "1 + Third" you will get an error because VBA doesn't look at "Third" as a number anymore.  Strange but true.

Comment: Thats correct, `FormatPercent` returns a string (it has to, there is a percentage sign on the end!). If you want to treat it as a number store it as `dblvar=1/3*100` and only format it as a percentage when you want to display/save it

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
   Dim Third As Variant
   Third = Format(1 / 3, "##.00%")
   MsgBox (Third)
```

Comment: Thanks Remou!  That was really what I was looking for- I haven't seen that in the past.  Have a great weekend!- Tommy